# Cannot deploy Firebase Cloud Functions [Cannot find module 'protobufjs/minimal']

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

This error happened after I update firebase-functions and firebase-admin

```
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.4",
"firebase-admin": "^6.0.0"
```

Full Error

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Error: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore client library for Node.js. Make sure to install the "@google-cloud/firestore" npm package. Original error: Error: Cannot find module 'protobufjs/minimal'
```

This is all dependencies I have

```
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"compose-middleware": "^4.0.0",
"cors": "^2.8.4",
"cuid": "^1.3.8",
"exponent-server-sdk": "^2.3.1",
"express": "^4.15.4",
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
"firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.4",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"query-string": "^6.1.0"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe roll back to v5/v1? All you should need is below for cloud functions and firestore interactions.

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Below is what my package.json shows, and my stuff works fine:

```
"firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
"firebase-functions": "^1.0.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

how about [installing](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-local-packages)  the missing [protobufjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) package with `npm install` or `npm update` ... maybe even explicitly add `"protobufjs": "^6.8.8"` - or install it with `npm install protobufjs`?